# required constructor seems confusing

Tags: swift

why do private properties with an initial value still require the init constructor (even though it does nothing for it)?

```
struct Person {
    private var middle: String = "A"

    var first: String
    var last: String
    
    init(first: String, last: String) {
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    }

    func printName() {
        print("\(first) \(middle). \(last)")
    }
}

let someone = Person(first: "", last: "")
someone.printName()
```

this just seems broken to me because if I remove the private accessor it's ok. I am sure there is something to explain this behavior and I am just curious what it is.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, the private property is not initialised in your constructor and it isn't needed. Your code compiles and runs, so again what are you asking?

Comment: If you omit the explicitly initializer, it generates an initializer, `init(middle:first:last:)` (where `middle` has a default property), but because `middle` is `private`, so is the initializer. You could define `middle` to be `private(set) var` or with `private let`, then the error will go away.

Comment: I have never seen private(set) before so that is interesting. with a search I found some more info on that https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-magic-public-getter-private-setter/

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You merely showed some code and called it "broken" without explanation. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the explicitly initializer, it generates a memberwise initializer, `init(middle:first:last:)` (where `middle` happens to have a default value), but because `middle` is `private`, so is this initializer.

As [the documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID19) says:

> The default memberwise initializer for a structure type is considered private if any of the structure’s stored properties are private. Likewise, if any of the structure’s stored properties are file private, the initializer is file private. Otherwise, the initializer has an access level of internal.

If `middle` wasn't marked as a variable that could be set (either by making it a constant with `private let` or setting only the setter to be private (with `private(set) var`, then only `init(first:last:)` would be created on your behalf.

Answer (score 2):

The default memberwise initializer becomes private when middle name is delcared private inspite of having a stored property because as per [Apple docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) "*You can also set and modify the initial value for a stored property during initialization*"

Since middle name is a **var**, it still can be modified during initialisation even though it is a stored property. Thus the default memberwise initializer becomes private.